# Good Urdu Translations of the Bible from the Masoretic and one of the Textus Receptuses, or just either?

Tags: bible, bible-translation, translation, language, kjv-onlyism

I am looking for urdu translations that are reasonably close to the reconstructions of the Hebrew Masoretic text and/or Greek Textus Receptus, being a literal translation. Like how despite the KJV translators deciding to translate the first verse "In the beginning created God, the Heaven and the Earth," because the Context clearly shows that the firmament is called "the Heavens," and the Schlachter 2000 translates it "Im Anfang schuf Gott **die Himmel** und die Erde --" the "heavens."

Not Young's Literal translation, because words can have different meanings, but obviously not "correcting" Luke 5 where Jesus tells Peter to let down all of the Nets, but Peter being a word the Bible says I can't say, and I agree, decided: I know better than you, I'll let down just the one net, like the N.I.V. does.

Technically it does not have to be close to the King James, but just as close word-for-word to an english Bible. Unfortunately even then, they might contradict each other, like the Spanish and English K.J.V.'s...

Pray this isn't that confusing...

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). I would recommend that you edit this question down seriously to eliminate the miscellaneous chatter and focus it on your specific question. For some tips, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this: a Friend just gave it to me in private: http://textus-receptus.com/wiki/Urdu_Bible